Asymptotically, how many permutations on $S_n$ have order exactly $k$, when $k$ is fixed and $n$ goes to infinity?
If $n$ and $k$ are positive integers, I'll denote by $N_{n,k}$ the number of permutations in $S_n$ with order $k$. I'd like to understand the behaviour of $N_{n,k}$ when $n$ goes to infinity while $k$ is fixed, at least for simple enough $k$.
I'm interested in getting the limit of the probabilities $P_n$ of picking $\sigma$ in $S_n$ (with uniform distribution) with order exactly $k$, given that $\sigma^k=e$, the identity. More precisely, I'm trying to see if $P_n\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, or if at least a subsequence of $(P_n)_n$ converges to $1$.
It is true that $$\displaystyle P_n=\frac{N_{n,k}}{\sum_{i\vert k}N_{n,i}}.$$ If $k=p$ is prime, then $$P_n=\frac{N_{n,p}}{N_{n,1}+N_{n,p}}=\frac{N_{n,p}}{1+N_{n,p}}\longrightarrow 1$$ as $N_{n,p}\rightarrow\infty$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$.It is not as straightforward even in the case where $k$ is the product of two primes, or the square of a prime.
Does anybody know the asymptotic behaviour of $N_{n,k}$? Is it known whether the limit I'm looking for converges? or at least a subsequence? (for example, $P_{nk}\rightarrow 1$ or $P_{k^n}\rightarrow 1$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$, or something like that, would be great!).

Equation (2.6) of a 1986 paper by Wilf gives an asymptotic formula for $f(k,n)$, the number of permutations $\sigma$ in $S_n$ such that $\sigma^k$ is the identity. In the subsequent lines is the assertion that the same asymptotic formula holds for $g(k,n)$, the number of permutations in $S_n$ with order exactly $k$. Presumably the details therein are sufficient for verifying this latter assertion, which would imply that the limit in question does equal $1$ for every $k$ and for the full sequence of $n$.
Side note: you might be interested in this article by Granville that talks more about the structure of permutations and the analogy with factorizations of integers.

Thanks! This was very helpful. Would you happen to know what they mean by $\mu(m/d)$? they don't seem to explain it there.

@Susana: that's probably the Mobius function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).
